What DLL is WinDbg's dt command implemented in?
I know that most of the WinDbg extensions that are used with the exclamation mark, like !time, etc. are implemented inside the kdext.dll that are in:
"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinDbg_1.2402.24001.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\amd64\winxp"

folder for the new WinDbg.
But where is the implementation of commands without the exclamation mark?
In my case I am interest about the dt command.

(replying in comment because it's a guess): dt is in dbghelp.dll which also exports functions like SymGetTypeFromName and  SymGetTypeInfo. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092609/how-to-get-field-names-and-offsets-of-a-struct-using-dbghlp-and-pdb

@Remko hmm, interesting. Thanks. I was thinking it's in dbgeng.dll. I was actually trying to see how they implemented it. Can't seem to find any symbols for it, not even something in it to place a breakpoint on.

ftr, dbgeng!ProcessCommands is where windbg parses input for its commands. you can use the help for each command (like dt -?), as a good anchor point to locate the function responsible for its implementation.

@AliRizvi-Santiago: thanks, I'll check. Just from curiosity, where did you get the symbols for the dbgeng from?

ah, weird. symbols for 10.0.25324.1001 (both 7423359078CFAAAD2123C34621B4EBD71 and 314DA9A27F9A8D5B8088A2E1FD518B831) 404 on msdl.microsoft.com. however, i have 7423359078CFAAAD2123C34621B4EBD71, and EFBB90B73FCE200AB2D6B1E98F4425E31 (unsure of the version) cached.

some others that i have cached for dbgeng over the years are 20D20B1FC2B74297BEC7C53CA580C39C1 , 5218B30138E2ACD50248CA4E795AB4681 , 90935CDF52AA4C42BCFC45A66060DDDA1 , 9778C914F4E34889AE3C24D694B132141 , A79F2B4019AA455E822ABA817821F19C1 , and E2110EBB27F595BCA2EFE6B3C61ED60B1... (maybe one of these will work for you). just in case, you can get the pdb via https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/dbgeng.pdb/$GUIDandAGE/dbgeng.pdb, with the dll usually sitting next to it as https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/dbgeng.pdb/$GUIDandAGE/dbgeng.dll.

@AliRizvi-Santiago hey, sorry for late response. How do you download those PDBs and DLLs from the links you gave? If I just put one of those long IDs into the URLs, I get a blank screen.
